# How does PHP SOAP class transformation work and how do I get consistent list results?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

So I am currently trying to implement an external API call using the [PHP SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) - and I found that it works in a pretty weird way.

Let's say I have the following WSDL definition:

```
<xs:element name="someParamList">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="someParam" type="someParam"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Which might return either:

```
<someParamList>
  <someParam>foo</someParam>
  <someParam>bar</someParam>
</someParamList>
```

or:

```
<someParamList>
  <someParam>foo</someParam>
</someParamList>
```

I've mapped someParamList to `SomeParamListClass`
and someParam to `SomeParamClass` using the `classmap` attribute. This works fine in general, **BUT** depending on the result I don't always get an `array` of `SomeParamClass`. If there is only 1 result in the list, PHP will directly set the object instead of an array with a single object in it.

I tried to transform the data in `__construct` `__set` or the normal setter but neither one is called.

So:
Why is the SoapClient acting so weird and why does it never call the constructor or the setters?
And how do I get consistent lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like various deserialization routines, the SoapClient doesn't pass the values to a constructor or setter that you can intercept, it just creates the objects internally with the values "magically" set up.

What you can do instead is use the `typemap` option rather than `classmap`, which lets you assign callbacks for converting types, rather than class names.

However, the "smart" list formatting can be by-passed more easily, using the `$options` parameter:

> `features` option is a bitmask of ... SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS ...

This isn't really described anywhere, but it forces *every* element of the decoded XML to be an array, rather than trying to guess which are single and which are multiple. This may mean you'll have to write `$response[0]['foo'][0]['bar'][0]` a lot, but at least it's predictable.

So:

```
$client = new SoapClient(
    $wsdl,
    [
        // other options which you're already passing here...
        'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. This brings some light into the dark, altough I don't understand why those things work "magically" and don't just call the setters.

This option would indeed make the behaviour predictably, but I would also have to handle all the single value elements as array which doesn't really make me happy.

I think I'm gonna take a look into the `typemap` and see if I can implement a generic solution for all my lists.

Comment: @PatrickWinkelmayer "Why" is always a tricky question, but bear in mind that it's not that the parser is *skipping* the setters; it simply doesn't *need* them, because it's not actually running any PHP. Writing C code to populate an object with the appropriate class name and values is *easier* than writing C code to check for and dynamically call custom PHP `__set` methods, or marshal the values into some intermediate form to pass to custom PHP `__construct` methods.